# mysql pdo get range of rows

Tags: mysql, database

i have a table with about 100 rows , and i want every time to get rows between number and number , like this

if `i=1` i want to get the rows `0 1 2 3 4`

if `i=2` i want to get the rows `5 6 7 8 9`

if `i=3` i want to get the rows `10 11 12 13 14`

and maybe the last value of i will just take 3 or 4 rows not 5
i think the solution will be something like this

```
select * from question limit (i-1)*5 , i*5-1
```

but doesn't work , cos i don't know how to use variable in a query , and when i tried it for i=1 it doesn't work and i got a syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to `LIMIT` is the zero-based starting row index. The second one is the number of rows. So, if you're always looking for five rows:

```
SELECT * FROM question LIMIT (i-1)*5 , 5
```

(You'll have to calculate `(i-1)*5` with whatever language you're using to build the query, and pass an actual number to MySQL).

Comment: it works , thank you for help and for description , i will accept answer

Comment: but when i used it in PDO like this i got an error `$query = "SELECT * FROM question LIMIT :start , 5";
        $sth = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $sth->execute(array(
            ':start' => $start
        ));
        return $sth;`

Comment: Strange, I read somewhere that you could pass values to limit on prepared statements. So I guess you'll have to inject directly into the query body.